# Azure - TypeInitialization error

Tags: c#, azure, mono

I'm getting the following a Type Initialization error when I call my Azure MobileService client:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for
 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient 
---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Net.Http.HttpMethod:get_Post (): method body is empty.
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at rpitemp.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

In years of programming, I've never seen a "Invalid IL code" exception

I'm currently calling it like this:

```
           MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient("https://<removed>.azure-mobile.net/", "<keyhere>");
```

What's the issue? This code is to be run using Mono on a Raspberry Pi.